# Keep only one square bracket in php string

Tags: php

My php code is giving result in double brackets like this:

> [["Faisalabad Belt",11.428571428571]],

But I want to get result only in single square bracket like this:

> ["Faisalabad Belt",11.428571428571],

I have tried using `str_replace()` but it is not giving me the desired results. It either replaces brackets from one side or the other but not properly replaces from both sides. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<?php
  echo (str_replace('[[','[',json_encode($poster)));
?>,
```

Sorry if you find the question clear.

Comment: what generated the initial string?

Comment: add the code that is making `$poster`

Comment: `[[` won't touch `]]`.

Comment: Don't you also need to run `str_replace(']]',']', ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace` also accepts arrays... One call and get all of them replaced at the same time

```
<?php echo (str_replace(['[[', ']]'], ['[', ']'], json_encode($poster))) ;  ?>
```

Comment: not including the extra [] in the first place is a better option

Comment: @Dagon I agree, but you'd be amazed at some of the strings I've had to work with...

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 $pattern = array('[[', ']]');
 $replacement = array('[', ']');
 echo str_replace($pattern, $replacement, json_encode($poster));
```

am sure this an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $result = json_encode($poster);
  $result = str_replace('[[','[', $result);
  $result = str_replace(']]',']', $result);

  echo $result;
```

If $result was equal to `"[['Hello', 1111]]"` then the result would be `"['Hello', 1111]"`

Answer (score 0):

`$string = '[["Faisalabad Belt",11.428571428571]],';`

`$result = str_replace(array('[[', ']]'), array('[', ']'), $string);`

`$result` is now `["Faisalabad Belt",11.428571428571],`